# How to use Clamscan to scan for files larger than 4GB

Tags: split, clamav

I need to scan files larger than 4GB, I tried the following solutions:

1- I tried to edit the clamd.conf and set the
MaxScanSize 100000M
MaxFileSize 100000M
(Just any arbitrary size that's larger than 4GB.)

2- And used `clamscan` with --max-filesize=20000M --max-scansize=20000M
And this one worked for a large amount of files but not files larger than 4GB

I read somewhere that you can use the `split` command to split larger files and then direct them to `clamscan`.

But i didn't understand what does it do exactly and how to use with the `clamscan` command that worked for the most part.
Here is the `clamscan` command that worked.
For 101GB of files
It successfully scanned 95GB out of them and left the rest.

`clamscan --max-filesize=20000M --max-scansize=20000M -r --bell -v -i --move=/home/username/Documents/infected /home/username/Documents/`

It gave the warning that the maximum size is 4GB and it was reset back to 4GB and then started.

Please let me know what does the `split` command does exactly and how to use it if i am scanning a large directory.

Also, should I ever use `sudo clamscan /` for the whole system ? or is the home folder (or what ever directory that don't require root privileges) enough?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/193059/320598: "* I'm using clamav/clamscan, where the man page say's it can scan files up to 4GB.*" So did you try to read the manual page?